# Automatically add newly created objects to list

Tags: python

Say I have a class called A and i want to list all the objects created from that particular class. This is what i have done till now and It raises `AttributeError: type object 'A' has no attribute 'items'` How to do this?

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []
        self.items.append(self)

    @classmethod
    def list_objects(cls):
        return cls.items


a = A()
b = A()
print(A.list_objects())

# Expected output is [a,b]
```

Comment: `self.items` is an instance attribute. Move it to the class body.

Comment: Note that storing instances in a list this way will result in garbage collection issue, i.e they are not going to be garbage collected unless you remove them from the list manually.  Consider using a [WeakSet](https://docs.python.org/2/library/weakref.html#weakref.WeakSet) if order is not an issue.

Comment: The question is answered so I just want to add that this usually isn't a good idea because it introduces global state, making reusing and testing more difficult.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would need the list to be at the class level, not instance level

```
class A:
    items = []

    def __init__(self):
        A.items.append(self)

    @classmethod
    def list_objects(cls):
        return cls.items
```

Then you would see

```
>>> a = A()
>>> b = A()
>>> A.list_objects()
[<__main__.A object at 0x02B77230>, <__main__.A object at 0x02B772D0>]
```

Comment: Just figured it out now myself, but not answering now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is in the `self.items = []` part, as you initialise a new `items` empty list for each instance of class `A` you create. So in your case each object of class `A` will have an instance member `items`, containing itself only.

So first of all you need to move your `items` list to the class level, and then in the `__init__` add `self` to that list.

If you are going to need this functionality for many classes, I would suggest to go with the following solution:

```
@track_objects
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pass  # your init code here

>>> a = A()
>>> b = A()
>>> A.items
[<__main__.A instance at 0x1004873f8>, <__main__.A instance at 0x100487488>]
```

and this is the `@track_objects` implementation:

```
def track_objects(klass):
    klass.items = []
    orig_init = klass.__init__

    def init_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.items.append(self)

        return orig_init(self, *args, **kwargs)
    klass.__init__ = init_wrapper

    return klass
```